# How to import data and create a scatter plot in R?

Tags: r

I have `334` records, with two columns:

- Column (1): Resolution
- Column (2): Number of images with a specific resolution

How can I make a scatter plot in `R` with this data? Is there a way to ***import*** the records, since it will be time consuming to enter `334` records?

Comment: [Quick-R](http://www.statmethods.net/graphs/scatterplot.html) is a good resources for beginning in R. Import/Export facilities are described in the manual, [R Data Import/Export](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-data.html) (see e.g. section 2, which described the use of `read.table()` among others).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you do not know how to get data into R nor create a scatterplot, it sounds like you are very new to R.

You might want to use a program that lends a hand.

- [rstudio](http://rstudio.org/) has a `Workspace - import dataset` menu; I'd recommend Rstudio, particularly if you are very new to R.
- [Rcmdr](http://socserv.mcmaster.ca/jfox/Misc/Rcmdr/) also has GUI options for getting data into R

As always Quick-R provides a helpful starting point:

- [importing data](http://www.statmethods.net/input/importingdata.html)
- [scatterplots](http://www.statmethods.net/graphs/scatterplot.html)

More generally, it sounds like you need to spend some time with some introductory instructional material on R. Here are my [suggested startings points](http://jeromyanglim.blogspot.com/2009/06/learning-r-for-researchers-in.html).